# compiling problem in winedt

Tags: compiling, winedt

Recently I started to use Winedt and I have the following problem. When I compile a document, in case of an error I correct the lines. The thing is that in order to compile once more I have to either terminate the previous compilation process or wait until it is finished. But it often takes too long to wait so I abort by pressing the cancelling button or Shift + Esc.

Next thing that happens next time I try to compile the document:

! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.

Impossible to compile. A temporary solution to this problem is to delete .aux file and compile from scratch. But it becomes very annoying to do this every time.

Does anyone has an advice regarding this issue?

Comment: When you get an error press "x" on your keyboard and then enter. This will finish the compilation in a sane way and normally you will then be able to compile again.

Comment: Otherwise you can press "e" and WinEdt will open your document at the line where the error is.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That works, thank you very much.

Comment: @Arzigoglu From what you have written I couldn't conclude what does it have to do with my problem. But it also solves it. Thank you.

Comment: When you get an error you can press "x" or "e". If you press "e" WinEdt will open your document at the line where the error is, instead of simply terminate the compilation

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think you already gave an answer like this. Are you able to find the duplicate?